# Hyperlink to play youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to create a hyperlink on your web page that can play an embedded youtube video on the same page.?

Comment: I'm not sure this is valid for `iframe` objects in-use at this time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can easily do this with the [Youtube Player API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Playback_controls)

If you have a read through that document, you'll see it's pretty easy to have your own controls and extend the player.

**Example**

```
// Get element holding the video (embed or object)
var player = document.getElementById("myYouTubePlayer");

//Create a simple function and check if player exists
function play() {
    if(player) {
        player.playVideo();
    }
}
```

Then in your HTML simply

```
<a href="#" onclick="play()">Play Youtube Video</a>
```

Comment: Worked a treat. Thank you so much..!

Comment: Is there a jsfiddle version of this anywhere? Thanks for answering the question

Comment: not enough information provided to repeat the example.