# bootstrap youtube video modal plays automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

As the webpage is opened, all the videos starts playing at the background automatically after 5 seconds i.e., the audio is heard even before clicking the image. how can i stop this from happening, the video has to open on button click and close. The videos have to work only on button click and close.

how would i achieve this? this is the fiddle
    https://jsfiddle.net/aaronfranco/L6xvLcuL/14/

```
<script>
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
$("#myModal").modal({backdrop: false});
});

$("#myBtn1").click(function(){
$("#myModal1").modal({backdrop: false});
});

$("#myBtn2").click(function(){
$("#myModal2").modal({backdrop: false});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure `Autoplay = 0` [Stop youtube video autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861987/stop-youtube-video-autoplay)

Then you can control when to play exactly using youtube api [Hyperlink to play youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614489/hyperlink-to-play-youtube-video)

Answer (score 1):

Just set autoplay=0. It's boolean. 0 far false 1 for true.

```
<iframe class="size" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rFuEu3dj-nA?autoplay=0" ;frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

after ?autoplay in youtube link.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your iframes are loading automatically and playing the videos, even though you have not shown the dialog yet.

You could change to use a single modal element, do NOT specify the src value on the iframe, then fill the src value from your button click event so the frame only starts loading when you open the dialog, i.e.

```
$('#myModal iframe').attr('src', movieURL);
$('#myModal').modal();
```

Comment: I prefer this idea as well, as it will be better for page load as well.

Comment: how would i implement it for three videos as in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in you `<iframe>` code where a attribute `autoplay` is there with value 1 which fires event to play video automatically when opens

> Change `autoplay` value from 1 to 0

By changing value to 0 u tell browser not to play video automatically. Here is the code

```
<iframe class="size" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rFuEu3dj-nA?autoplay=0" ;frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Now with Jquery on button click change the attribute value

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('iframe').attr('autoplay','1');
});
```

Comment: but the video has to play automatically upon button click

Comment: and also in the background we can hear the audio even before doing anything

Comment: how do i implement to the above fiddle